# how to append Double quotes (" ") For a String Array Varible in java

Tags: java, append, double-quotes

I am working with  writing files.I have a string array as in loop 
I need to append double quotes for the all values which are writing it on  files . Can any one help me how to append double quotes for the all values in String Array.Thanks in advance`

Comment: Have you tried anything yet though?

Comment: Yead ,I tried  I am able to append double quotes to my array values, I tried this     "\""+a[x]+"\"".
Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you might be looking for is as follows:

```
region.append("\"").append(a[z]).append("\"").append(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 8, what you probably want to do is

```
String region = Arrays.stream(a)
    .map(s -> String.format("\"%s\"", s)) // add double quotes around each string
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","); // comma-separate values
```

Comment: @araknoid, since OP didn't show any effort in question, this is effectively a free-for-all when it comes to answers.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov You are correct but since the java version is not specified in the question, it should be at least in the answer.

Comment: Yup , I tried  with this its working fine  thank u guys

Answer (score 0):

1. for each string, surround it with quotes
2. for each string, except the last one, add a comma to its end
3. write all strings in the file.

ex:

```
int l = myStrings.length;
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
    // Adds " to the begning of the string and ", to the end of the string.
    myStrings[i] = "\"" + mystrings[i] + "\",";
    // if you want to use String.format:
    //myStrings[i] = String.format("\"%s\",", myStrings[i]);

    // if it is the last string, remove the unwanted comma
    if(i == l-1){
        // gets the substring of the last string in the array, excluding only
        // the last character, because it is an unwanted comma
        myStrings[i] = myStrings[i].substring(0,l);
    }

    // Write in your file here
    // region.append(myStrings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
str.add("One");
str.add("Two");
str.add("Three");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for (String i : str) {
    array.put(i);
}
JSONObject userData = new JSONObject();
userData.put("user", array);
print("" + userData)
```

OutPut:

```
{"user": ["One", "Two", "Three"]}
```